Multiple Dependent Variables, One Independent - with dummy variables
I am trying to run regression models and don't know what type of regression to be running.
I have one independent variable (binary variable) and 8 dependent variables (3 discrete, 3 categorical, 2 nominal), and one moderating variable (nominal).
My independent variable is the use of TikTok and I am looking at its impact on the other variables.
I was looking at using either the multinomial logistics or MANCOVA, but unsure of which would best apply. Also how do I incorporate the moderating variable?

Are you interested in the relationships among the dependent variables, or are you willing to model each DV separately?
